# RHEL 6: View boot messages "behind" the splash screen

Tags: linux, redhat, fedora

I know there was a way to do the above in Fedora. I cannot for the life of me remember what the key was; nor can I find documentation via a web search.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> works also.  I remember it as "details".

Comment: Ah, easier to remember!

Comment: Thanks, I forgot which command so your answer helped.

Answer (score 13):

- Interrupt the GRUB by hitting the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key
- Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit
- Remove the `rhgb quiet` at the kernel line
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> and hit <kbd>b</kbd> to continue booting

Comment: I follow the above command but when i dot that.  Is going to command mode and showing different services are starting, but at the bottom it is getting stuck saying starting certmonager and the cursor is continuous blinking. after that i wait and wait but noting happens

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you are asking, you should just be able to hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to show the startup messages.  To make it go away permanently, remove "rhgb" from the kernel line in /etc/grub.conf.

Answer (score 3):

Just found out: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> seems to work on virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to edit the kernel line in your grub setup when you boot.
Just remove the **rhgb**

The changes are not permanent.